# keyup or onclick event for checkbox generated server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know the syntax for setting a click event or keyup event on a checkbox in the following c# code? I'm trying to set the 3rd parameter htmlAttributes (after the 2nd parameter of true, see below:

```
Response.Write(Html.CheckBox("chkStatus_" + item.Value, true) + " " 
                                          + item.Text + "<br />");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("chkStatus_" + item.Value, true, 
                                  new { onclick = "doSomething();" }); %>
```

or Razor

```
@Html.CheckBox("chkStatus_" + item.Value, true, 
                                  new { onclick = "doSomething();" })
```