# html helper syntax to go to a javascript function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [keyup or onclick event for checkbox generated server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025524/keyup-or-onclick-event-for-checkbox-generated-server-side)

I searched and didn't find anything, i have a checkbox that when changed i want to go to a function.  like this:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onchange="upperCase()" />
```

Currently i have this

`@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.user, new { @id = "chk" + item.id, @class = "chk" })`

What is the syntax for going to a javascript function in a html helper?

Comment: Did you try @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.user, new { onchange = "upperCase()"}) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025524/keyup-or-onclick-event-for-checkbox-generated-server-side